# Почему выводится в качестве ответа иероглифы?

Tags: c++

Печатаю: 1 + 2 - 3 * 4 / 5. Должно выводить: 12345, а выводит иероглифы. В чем проблема?

```
for (int j = 0; j <= str.size() - 1; j++) {
    if (str[j] != '+') {
        arr_op[m] = str[j];
        m++;
    }

    if (str[j] != '-') {
        arr_op[m] = str[j];
        m++;
    }

    if (str[j] != '*') {
        arr_op[m] = str[j];
        m++;
    }

    if (str[j] != '/') {
        arr_op[m] = str[j];
        m++;
    }
}

for (int j = 0; j <= m - 1; j++) {
    cout << arr_op[j];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

А почему выводите массив arr_op, тогда как надо arr_sign?
Это во-первых. А, во-вторых, конструкция с if'ами делает не то, что задумано. Смотрите в сторону клюсевого слова continue.

Comment: @gecube да, тупая ошибка была. Исправил код. А сейчас вот ввожу: 1+2-3, выводит 1111+++2222---3333. Почему? =/

Comment: Из-за ifов, идущих подряд. Еще раз - или в каждый if добпвьте ключевое слово continue, или используйте if-else...